# Memory management - should I nil and release object by some orders?

Tags: objective-c, ios, memory-management

For example, I created an array and put some custom class into it. Should I nil and release them by a certain order? If I put background ASIHTTPRequests in a array, will there be a leak if I release the array first? Is it the same in ARC? Thank you for your answers.

Comment: Thanks for your remind, I tried but didn't find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add an object to an `NSArray` it is automatically retained, then when you `release` the array a `release` signal is sent to all the objects in that array. So:

```
-(void)someMethod{

   NSString *newString = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"Hello"]; //newString retainCount = 1
   NSArray *newArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: newString]; //newString retainCount = 2 

   [newArray release];  //newString retainCount = 1
   [newString release];  //newString retainCount = 0

}
```

Is the same as:

```
-(void)someMethod{

   NSString *newString = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"Hello"]; //newString retainCount = 1
   NSArray *newArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: newString]; //newString retainCount = 2 

   [newString release];  //newString retainCount = 1
   [newArray release];  //newString retainCount = 0

}
```

In fact the 2nd code is a very common practice when you want to create an array of objects without taking care of individual references to those objects.

Comment: Thanks @whitelionV. I think I dont need to release them in ARC, but I still need nil those properties in viewDidUnload?

Comment: If you are using Automatic reference count, then iOS is responsible for your memory. Assigning nil to your unused pointers is a good practice, and you should do it, but it 'shouldn't' make a difference 'memory-wise'... it might make ARC job easier, but I'm not sure